# Ruby Exercise: Count the numbers in an array between a given range

Tags: ruby

So working through the above exercise and found this solution on GitHub.

```
def count_between arr, lower, upper
  return 0 if arr.length == 0 || lower > upper
  return arr.length if lower == upper
  range = (lower..upper).to_a
  arr.select { |value| range.include?(value) }.length
end
```

I understand what the first three lines mean and why they return the values they do.  What I'd like to understand are the following lines of code.

Line 4 (below) is defining "range" as a variable and uses the lower...upper as the range variables (just discovered you don't need to put an integer value in a range.  What does '.to_a' mean, can't seem to find it in the ruby docs, and what does it do?

```
 range = (lower..upper).to_a
```

Line 5 (below) is using an Array#select method and its saying select this value if the value is included in this range and then give me the Array#length of all selected values, but I don't quite understand A. what |value| is doing and what it means. B. range.include?(value) means is this value included in this range I am assuming.

```
 arr.select { |value| range.include?(value) }.length
```

Answer (score 6):

Actually, I'd simplify to this:

```
def count_between arr, lower, upper
  return 0 if lower > upper
  arr.count{|v| (lower..upper).include?(v)}
end
```

`to_a` is documented [here](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-to_a); it returns an Array containing each element in the Range.  However, there's no reason to call `to_a` on the Range before calling `include?`.

There's also no reason to special-case the empty array.

Returning the length of the array when `lower` equals `upper` makes no sense.

`value` is the name given to the value the block is called with.  I think a simple `v` is better for such a trivial case.

`select` calls the block for each value in `arr` and returns a new Array containing the elements for which the block returns `true`, so the length of that new Array is the number of matching values.  However, `count` exists, and makes more sense to use, since the count is all we care about.

**Update:** As @steenslag points out in the comments, [Comparable#between?](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Comparable.html#method-i-between-3F) can be used instead of creating a Range on which to call `include?`, and this eliminates the need to ensure that `lower` is less than or equal to `upper`:

```
def count_between arr, lower, upper
  arr.count{|v| v.between?(lower, upper)}
end
```

Comment: `arr.count{|v| v.between?(lower, upper)}` is enough.

Comment: Oh, I meant `return 0 if lower>upper` is unnecessary.

Comment: @steenslag Oh, cool, that's even better.  I didn't actually look at the documentation I linked to to see that the arguments to `between?` are `min` and `max` and not just boundaries in any order.

Answer (score 1):

`to_a` means convert to array

```
irb(main):001:0> (1..5).to_a
=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

[select](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-select) method passes each element to the block and *Returns a new array containing all elements of ary for which the given block returns a true value.*. In your case it simply checks if the value is contained in the `range` array. `range` is an array not a range.

```
## if arr is [1,5] for eg:

irb(main):005:0> [1,5].select {|value| range.include?(value)}
=> [1, 5]
irb(main):006:0> [1,5].select {|value| range.include?(value)}.length
=> 2
```

so the elements of `arr` are contained in the `|value|` variable inside the block.

Answer (score 0):

It's a block.

As the documentation says: select "Returns a new array containing all elements of ary for which the given block returns a true value."

So for each object in `arr` it is passed to the block in which you provide whatever code you want to that returns `true` or `false`, and the select statement uses this result to add the value to the the array that it returns. And after that, `length` is called on the array.

So you have an array, you filter the array to contain only the numbers that are in the range, and then you take the length - effectively counting the number of elements.